# How to parse and match with multiple regexes

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have an input data of the form:

```
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
```

I need to parse through this data and the IN: / OUT: /INOUT: depending on three regexes given as:

```
regex1 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
regex2 = r"\[2\]\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
regex3 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s.*?.\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
```

My output should be:

```
IN_r1 2.12 INOUT_r1 3.52
IN_r3 2.12 INOUT1_r3 3.52 OUT_r3 2.42 INOUT2_r3 2.62

OUT_r2 2.42 INOUT_r2 2.62
IN_r3 2.12 INOUT1_r3 3.52 OUT_r3 2.42 INOUT2_r3 2.62

IN_r1 2.12 INOUT_r1 3.52 
OUT_r2 2.42 INOUT_r2 2.62
IN_r3 2.12 INOUT1_r3 3.52 OUT_r3 2.42 INOUT2_r3 2.62
```

The code I tried:

```
import re
regex1 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
regex2 = r"\[2\]\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
regex3 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s.*?.\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"

data = "
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
"

lines = re.split("\[2]",data)

for line in lines:


    if re.search(regex1,data):
        tracks = re.findall(regex1,data,re.DOTALL)
        for track in tracks:
            input,inout = (float(z) for z in track)
            with open("checked_ant.txt",'a') as a:
                print("IN_r1",input,"INOUT_r1",inout,file=a)
    elif re.search(regex2,data):
        tracks = re.findall(regex2,data,re.DOTALL)
        for track in tracks:
            output,inout = (float(z) for z in track)
            with open("checked_ant.txt",'a') as a:
                print("OUT_r2",output,"INOUT_r2",inout,file=a)
    elif re.search(regex3,data):
        tracks = re.findall(regex3,data,re.DOTALL)
        for track in tracks:
            input,inout1,output,inout2 = (float(z) for z in track)
            with open("checked_ant.txt",'a') as a:
                print("IN_r3",input,"INOUT1_r3",inout1,"OUT_r3",output,"INOUT2_r3",inout2,file=a)
```

The problem I face is that it does not parse correctly and it is not getting matched for each subdata beginning with [2]

Comment: Do you really want to _see_ the output you have labelled above, or do you want to _extract_ certain data?  If the latter, please show us what the data should look like e.g. in a list or dictionary.

Comment: do you care whether it's from IN or OUT or INOUT?

Comment: yes it should be from the specific IN or OUT or INOUT

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the data extracted needs to be printed in this form

Comment: but your expected output not contain such information. it just says you need extract all numbers.

Comment: @LeiYang yes but might have to enhance this script later hence need it in that way.

Comment: please modify your expected output to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @LeiYang I have made a small change in ```print``` of code and the output I want so that it would help in better understanding of what I require.

Comment: ```r1 r2 r3``` denote the regex to which it has matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I find the requirement quite strange(regex is provided and cannot change), I got the expected result. Can you try.

```
import re

s = '''[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)'''

r1 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
r2 = r"\[2\]\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"
r3 = r"\[2\]\s*IN:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s.*?.\s*OUT:\s*(\S+?)\s*INOUT:\s*(\S+?)\s"


def g(reg, s, n):
    return float(re.search(reg, s).group(n))


paras = s.split('\n\n')
for p in paras:
    if re.search(r1, p):
        print(f'IN_r1 {g(r1, p, 1)} INOUT_r1 {g(r1, p, 2)}')
    if re.search(r2, p):
        print(f'OUT_r2 {g(r2, p, 1)} INOUT_r2  {g(r2, p, 2)}')
    if re.search(r3, p):
        print(
            f'IN_r3 {g(r3, p, 1)} INOUT1_r3 {g(r3, p, 2)} OUT_r3 {g(r3, p, 3)} INOUT2_r3 {g(r3, p, 4)}')
```

---

**Update**

For better performance, you can match only once, and get the groups. Take r1 as example:

```py
gs = re.search(r1, p)
if gs:
    print(f'IN_r1 {gs.group(1)} INOUT_r1 {gs.group(2)}')
```

Comment: Thans for your answer. My mentor told me to strictly follow the regexes mentioned in my code. The float values being extracted from IN,OUT,INOUT need to be stored in input,output,inout present in the if-else conditions. The problem I am facing is that for every part starting with ```[2]``` I want to parse and check with the 3 mentioned regexes but somehow it just skips some parts starting with ```[2]```

Comment: if he writes regex(the most difficult part) for you, why not he write the remaining code?  i don't see anywhere in your regex that matches a `float`. the regex is not precise either.

Comment: No clue about that. I was hoping he would be more flexible with this. But he says that this regex format is a must for further enhancements.

Comment: yes this gives my required output! I just wanted to ask if the matches are being stored in {g(reg,s,n)} as float values or strings? And if I had to store them in float, what would I need to do?

Comment: `return float(re.search(reg, s).group(n))` updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234844/discussion-between-abcd-and-lei-yang).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex find all approach.  We can first search for each multiline section beginning with `[2]`, then find all data numbers and print them out in a single line.

```py
import re

inp = """[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)

[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
[2]   OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)
[2]   IN: 2.12    INOUT: 3.52  (Input)
      OUT: 2.42   INOUT: 2.62  (Output)"""

first  = 1
for m in re.finditer(r'\[\d+\](.*?)(?=\[\d+\]|$)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL):
    nums = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', m.group(1))
    if first != 1:
        print('')
    print(' '.join(nums), end='')
    first = 0
```

This prints:

```
2.12 3.52
2.12 3.52 2.42 2.62
2.42 2.62
2.12 3.52 2.42 2.62
2.12 3.52
2.42 2.62
2.12 3.52 2.42 2.62
```

Comment: I need the float value to be stored with the respective IN\OUT\INOUT as they need to be used for further enhancement.  My mentor said that the regexes given with the if-else conditions need to followed strictly.

Comment: @abcd I inquired into whether you needed to store the data, to which you replied `the data extracted needs to be printed in this form` ... this is my answer based on your comment.

Comment: oh sorry I might have not been clear, it is my mistake. I wanted to say that the data needs to be extracted with the respective IN,OUT or INOUT and then assigned to input,output,inout float values as can be seen in the 3 if-else conditions.